# How can I search the database from the filters/select boxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page that has a search box that I can search the sql database and display the results in a table.  I now have multiple ListBoxFor() Select boxes that I want to set up as option filters.  The ListBoxFor's are correctly populating from the database.

My Question is:

How can I search the database from the filters/select boxes?

Model:

```
 public int[] SelectedIds { get; set; }
 public List<LookupAgency> Agencies { get; set; } //many more like this below...
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index(string searchString, HomePageModel hpmodel)
        {
             // all projects
            var projects = _projectRepo.All;    
            var selectedAgencies = hpmodel.SelectedIds;

            var selectedAgencyItems = new List<LookupAgency>();
            int[] selectedAgencyArray = selectedAgencyItems.Select(s => s.Id).ToArray();

            // if we have a search string, search on it and filter results
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                projects = _projectRepo.All;
                projects = projects.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(searchString) ||
                     x.TIPNumber.Contains(searchString.ToLower()) ||
                     x.ProjectName.Contains(searchString)).OrderBy(x => x.ProjectName);
            }

            // return the projects to the view
            HomePageModel hpm = new HomePageModel();
            hpm.Project = projects;
            hpm.SelectedIds = selectedAgencies;
            hpm.Agencies = _projectRepo.GetAgencyItems();
            hpm.Categories = _projectRepo.GetCategoriesItems();
            hpm.ProjectTypes = _projectRepo.GetProjectTypes();
            hpm.FiscalYear = _projectRepo.GetFiscalYear();
            hpm.Phases = _projectRepo.GetPhases();
            hpm.FundingSources = _projectRepo.GetFundingSource();
            hpm.FundingTypes = _projectRepo.GetFundingTypes();
            hpm.MapService = _mapserviceRepo.All;

            return View(hpm);
        }
```

And the View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Search Database: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")    

        <!--Search Filter Multiselect-->
        <h5>Project Search</h5>
        <div>
            <h6>Search by Agency</h6>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.Agencies, "Id", "Name"))
        </div>
        <div>
            <h6>Search by Project Category</h6>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"), new { id = "projCategoryListBox" })
        </div>
        <div>
            <h6>Search by Project Type</h6>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.ProjectTypes, "Id", "Description"))
        </div>
        <h5>Funding Search</h5>
        <div>
            <h6>Search by Fiscal Year</h6>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.FiscalYear))
        </div>
        <div>
            <h6>Search by Phase</h6>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.Phases, "Id", "Name"))
        </div>
        <div>
            <h6>Search by Funding Source</h6>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.FundingSources, "Id", "Name"))
        </div>
        <div>
            <h6>Search by Funding Type</h6>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.FundingTypes, "Id", "Name"))
        </div>     
        <input type="submit" value="Find" autocomplete="on" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I guess the problem is, after I get back the int Id for the selected items, how do I search with that in linq?

Comment: I'm thinking it should be something like:


projects = projects.Where(x => x.AgencyId == ...




I'm getting back an Array of Ints for the Id in the db table, how can I filter the projects based on the selected agencies ?

Comment: Ok, I got it.  I had to loop through the array and check each one like so:

foreach (var agencyId in hpm.SelectedAgencyIds)
                {                    
                    // filter projects 
                    projects = projects.Where(x => x.AgencyId == agencyId);
                    
                }